# Processing XML in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, appium

I'm trying to learn XML processing in RubyMine, based on a tutorial on nokogiri.com and what I've found searching the forums on stackoverflow.com.

My code is:

```
Then /^I process an XML file:(.*?).$/ do |arg1|
  xml_str = Nokogiri::XML('<root>
  <sitcoms>
    <sitcom>
      <name>Married with Children</name>
      <characters>
        <character>Al Bundy</character>
        <character>Bud Bundy</character>
        <character>Marcy Darcy</character>
      </characters>
    </sitcom>
    <sitcom>
      <name>Perfect Strangers</name>
      <characters>
        <character>Larry Appleton</character>
        <character>Balki Bartokomous</character>
      </characters>
    </sitcom>
  </sitcoms>
  <dramas>
    <drama>
      <name>The A-Team</name>
      <characters>
        <character>John "Hannibal" Smith</character>
        <character>Templeton "Face" Peck</character>
        <character>"B.A." Baracus</character>
        <character>"Howling Mad" Murdock</character>
      </characters>
    </drama>
  </dramas>
</root>
')

  doc  = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)
  sleep 2
  puts "\ndoc class is " + doc.class.to_s
  sleep 2

  thing = doc.xpath("//character")
  sleep 2
  puts "\nthing class is " + thing.class.to_s
  sleep 2

  stop_value = thing.length
  idx = 0
  puts "\nthing length is #{stop_value}"
  if thing.empty?
    puts "\nthing is empty"
  else
    pits "\nthing is NOT empty"
  end

  while idx < stop_value
    puts "\n" + thing[idx].to_s
    idx += 1
  end
```

The class for "doc" is correct, but the class for "thing" is Nil.

I'm running RubyMine 8.0.3, Ruby 2.2.1, and Appium 1.5.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `Nokogiri::XML` twice: Once on line 2, where you assign the result to `xml_str`, and then again when you do `doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)`. If you change your code to only call it once, it works fine:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root>
  <sitcoms>
    <sitcom>
      <name>Married with Children</name>
      <characters>
        <character>Al Bundy</character>
        <character>Bud Bundy</character>
        <character>Marcy Darcy</character>
      </characters>
    </sitcom>
    <sitcom>
      <name>Perfect Strangers</name>
      <characters>
        <character>Larry Appleton</character>
        <character>Balki Bartokomous</character>
      </characters>
    </sitcom>
  </sitcoms>
  <dramas>
    <drama>
      <name>The A-Team</name>
      <characters>
        <character>John "Hannibal" Smith</character>
        <character>Templeton "Face" Peck</character>
        <character>"B.A." Baracus</character>
        <character>"Howling Mad" Murdock</character>
      </characters>
    </drama>
  </dramas>
</root>
')

puts "doc class is #{doc.class}"
# => doc class is Nokogiri::XML::Document

thing = doc.xpath("//character")
puts "thing class is #{characters.class}"
# => thing class is Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
```

Comment: Thanks, Jordan!!  Once I took out the 2nd call to nokogiri, my code worked!!